# How to start 389 Directory Server at boot

Tags: linux, ldap, 389-ds

How do I configure 389 Directory Server to start automatically during boot? I am using Fedora 18 and 389 DS version 1.3.0.2, build 2013.017.28. There does not seem to be any recent documentation on this on the 389 DS website. `chkconfig` doesn't do the trick.

Additionally, what is the recommended way to control the 389 DS processes? So far I've discovered:

```
1) systemctl [start,restart,stop] dirsrv.target controls the directory server.
2) [start,restart,stop]-ds-admin controls the admin server.
3) 389-console loads the admin console.
```

Are these the **best ways** to control 389?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start 389 Directory server at boot, you need to use the `systemctl` command.

This will allow you to start all instances you have in the system,

```
  systemctl enable dirsrv.target
```

In order to run a specific instance, use

```
  systemctl enable dirsrv@instname.service
```

For more details, please read the [documentation here.](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/docs/389ds/howto/howto-systemd.html)

Comment: How about starting the admin server at boot also?

Comment: Additionally, Is there a way to guarantee that 389 starts before my Samba processes start?